# Style callout in Flex PieChart?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, charts, pie-chart

Is it possible to style the string returned from the labelFunction so I can change color and font of the callout (inside)?  Or some other way?

(It seems like a big limitation to have that only return a string that is unstylable.)

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are properties of pie series, called color, fontFamily, which can do the job for u mite.
For further reference:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/series/PieSeries.html